# Docker run doesn't work

Tags: linux, docker

I've just got started with Docker and managed to install it.

Next, I watched and followed the instruction from this video at minute 14:00

How to Get Started with Docker
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iqqDU2crIEQ

```
wolf@linux:~$ docker images
REPOSITORY    TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED         SIZE
ubuntu        latest    f643c72bc252   3 weeks ago     72.9MB
hello-world   latest    bf756fb1ae65   11 months ago   13.3kB
wolf@linux:~$
```

I tried to run it ...

```
wolf@linux:~$ docker run -p 8080:80 --name hello -d hello-world
007somehashhere
wolf@linux:~$
```

However, when I checked it with `docker ps`, it's not there.

```
wolf@linux:~$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND   CREATED   STATUS    PORTS     NAMES
wolf@linux:~$
```

I tried to restart it, but it doesn't work too.

```
wolf@linux:~$ docker start hello 
hello
wolf@linux:~$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND   CREATED   STATUS    PORTS     NAMES
wolf@linux:~$
```

Tried different command, but doesn't help much.

```
wolf@linux:~$ docker container run -d -t hello-world
007somehashhere
wolf@linux:~$ 

wolf@linux:~$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND   CREATED   STATUS    PORTS     NAMES
wolf@linux:~$
```

What's wrong in this case and how do I make it work?

Comment: Your `hello-world` image is only 13.3kb, in the video his is over 1.0gb in size. I would guess your image doesn't really do much, so it stops running right after you `run` it.

Comment: To verify if your image indeed exits instantly, you should run `docker ps -a`, which lists the stopped containers as well, not only the currently running ones.

Comment: try `docker image inspect IMAGE [IMAGE...]` command to see more details about your image, may be that will help.